# Lucene - How to use TeeSinkTokenFilter?

Tags: java, lucene

Would anyone please explain how(and what for) to use the TeeSinkTokenFilter, from Lucene? An example would be much appreciated too =P. I didn't find the [official documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/sinks/TeeSinkTokenFilter.html) much clear , and have also looked up many sites, without much progress. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I didn't think the official documentation was very clear, either.  I think part of what made it so confusing is that it demonstrated two different features together in a way that made it hard to tell them apart.  Let me see if I can rewrite their example to just show the basic case.

```
TeeSinkTokenFilter source1 = new TeeSinkTokenFilter(
    new WhitespaceTokenizer(version, reader1));
TeeSinkTokenFilter.SinkTokenStream sink1 = source1.newSinkTokenStream();
TeeSinkTokenFilter.SinkTokenStream sink2 = source1.newSinkTokenStream();
source1.consumeAllTokens(); // all tokens get cached at this point

TokenStream final3 = new EntityDetect(sink1);
TokenStream final4 = new URLDetect(sink2);

d.add(new TextField("f3", final3, Field.Store.NO));
d.add(new TextField("f4", final4, Field.Store.NO));
```

This allows the final3 and final4 token streams to share the processing done by source1.  As the official documentation said, the order in which the streams are consumed is important, but as it doesn't say, the order appears to be indeterminate (or maybe alphabetical by field name).  I recommend using the consumeAllTokens method as I've done above.